# Print string literally in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, unicode

I was trying to write a function `convertStr` with JavaScript that will print strings literally when used with `console.log(convertStr(str))`.

Some examples for input and output

```
str = '\'"\n\\'
console.log(convertStr(str))
> '\'"\n\\'
```

For doing this `convertStr` should convert `'\'"\n\\'` to `'\'\\\'"\\n\\\\\''`.

Let us consider a simpler example

```
str = '\''
convertStr(str)              =====> '\'\\\'\''
console.log(convertStr(str)) =====> '\''
```

The first challenge here is to know whether we are enclosing str with `'` or `"`. I don't think this is possible without making assumption.

Let's assume that `str` is enclosed using `'`.

The other challenge is there are lot of cases to handle.

After searching the web I tried few solutions

#### Attempt 1:

I tried `JSON.stringify` which breaks when I use escaped string quotes inside `str`

```
console.log(JSON.stringify('\"')) =====> "\""
console.log(JSON.stringify('\'')) =====> "'"
```

This solution fails for case with single quotes. This also fails when we use unicode escape

```
console.log(JSON.stringify('\u2260') ====> "≠"
```

#### Attempt 2:

I tried using `str.replace(regex, replacestr)` but could not find a solution that works for all cases like unicode or things like `\x41` or `\0`.

Comment: when you say you want it to print it literally, do you mean in you example of `str = '\'"\n\\'` you also wish for it to print the opening and closing `'`? even though technically the value of `str` is `\'"\n\\ `?

Comment: @haxxton It might be sufficient to get value `\'"\n\\ `. We add `\'` to get single quotes or double quotes for now.

Comment: If you dont necessarily need a cross-browser solution, have you had a play with what is possible using [`String.raw()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw)

Comment: @haxxxton `String.raw`is promising. I'll take a look at it

Comment: I think you're likely to run into issues with backticks however. And i dont know if you'll ever necessarily get a solution to `'\''` as this is a way of getting the character `'` into your variable wrapped in `'`. As soon as that assignment is complete the escape character is gone.